# ejabberd mod_archive_odbc tables for storing messages

Tags: database, erlang, ejabberd, mod-archive-odbc

I am using **Ejabberd** for implementing a chat application, I turned ejabberd configuration to use **ODBC (mysql)** instead of using default **Mnesia** for database.

Now I compiled and configured **mod_archive_odbc** and restarted the server.

**Query is :** tables for archiving messages are not created by default. So do I need to run sql queries manually for creating tables or this is a problem with my configuration so that tables are not created ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be good if you could tell me how you went about setting up your mod_archive to work if you're using a 14.x release.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run query.

You can find an `.sql` file in the [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/blob/master/mod_archive/src/mod_archive_odbc_mysql.sql) which is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done it already. Its works fine.

Comment: Hi @GopalSRathore any chance you can share a sample of your config.yml file? I am trying to setup message archiving with same stack as you but I am having hard time doing this?

Comment: @rastko ... sure ... which version you are using?

Comment: I am using 15.04. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`mod_archive` implement [XEP-0136: Message Archiving](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html), which is now replace by [XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html).

`mod_mam` is included in ejabberd 15.06 and this is now the reference module for archiving. I suggest you turn to this version.